# Deformation retract - Example and theory question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Is it true that if you have a deformation retract of path connected spaces $A \subset X$, then the inclusion $i : A \rightarrow X$ and the retraction $r : X \rightarrow A$ give rise to isomorphisms of fundamental groups

$i_{\sharp} : \pi_1 (A) \rightarrow \pi_1(X)$ and $j_{\sharp} : \pi_1(X) \rightarrow \pi_1(A)$.

Is this true?-In case that the answer is yes: Does it hold that $i_{\sharp} ^{-1}  = j_{\sharp}$?

Concerning deformation retracts. Is it true that $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\} \times \{0\}$ is a deformation retract  of $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{(0,0,z);z \in \mathbb{R}\}$?- I would say the map $F(x,y,z,t)= (x,y,(1-t)z)$ does it, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first question Yes:** $r\circ i=Id_A$ then $r_{\sharp}\circ i_{\sharp}=Id_{\pi_1(A)}$ .
 Since $i\circ r$ is homotope to $Id_X$ then $i_{\sharp}\circ r_{\sharp}=Id_{\pi_1(X)}$, hence $i_{\sharp}$ is an isomorphism and $i_{\sharp}^{-1}=r_{\sharp}$.